# Create df from list (fill up to nth number value into one columns then continue..) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Would like to create the the df from a list that first 5 value should be in column a, then the next 5 value in another column etc, anyone have any idea? Below is the code. Thank you.

```
print (test_1)
['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', 1279', '1228', '1299', '1162', '1285', '1079', '1197', '1250', '1249', '1385', '1216', '1201', '1320', '1228', '1241', '1232', '1200', '1213', '1224', '1070','1224', '1070'...]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(test_1).reshape(22,5), columns = list("abcde"))
print (df)
      a     b     c     d     e     
0     01    02    03    04    05
0     06    07    08    09    10    
1   1279  1228  1299  1162  1285  
3   1079  1197  1250  1249  1385
```

Desired output:

```
print (df)
      a     b     c     d     e     
0     01  1279  ...   ...   ...    
1     02  1228  ...   ...   ...    
2     03  1299  ...   ...   ...  
3     04  1162  ...   ...   ...  
4     05  1285  ...   ...   ...    
5     06  1079  ...   ...   ... 
6     07  1197  ...   ...   ... 
7     08  1250  ...   ...   ... 
8     09  1249  ...   ...   ...  
9     10  1385  ...   ...   ...
```

Comment: Side note: **never** name a variable with a built-in, e.g. use `lst` or `list_` instead of `list`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Yes, it should be different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reshape(5,-1).T` where `-1` represent the new axis:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(li).reshape(5,-1).T, columns = list("abcde"))
```

Do not use `list` as variable name.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Simple and straight forward answer! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(L).reshape(5, 22).T, columns = list("abcde"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is help too :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary comprehension. Here is an example where `lst` has 30 items (and therefore 3 columns).

```
lst = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10',
       '1279', '1228', '1299', '1162', '1285', '1079', '1197', '1250', '1249', '1385',
       '1216', '1201', '1320', '1228', '1241', '1232', '1200', '1213', '1224', '1070',]

col_size = len(lst)//3

df = pd.DataFrame({col: lst[col_size*i: col_size*(i+1)]
                   for i, col in enumerate('abc')})

print (df)

    a     b     c
0  01  1279  1216
1  02  1228  1201
2  03  1299  1320
3  04  1162  1228
4  05  1285  1241
5  06  1079  1232
6  07  1197  1200
7  08  1250  1213
8  09  1249  1224
9  10  1385  1070
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is seem lengthy compare to above 2 answer. But this can be keep in mind too! Thanks again! :)